# How to compare 3 csv files base on File1 first column

Tags: bash, csv

I'm trying to compare 3 csv files in bash and save the result as new file either values are matching or not

File1.csv

```
    20180501,1000
    20180502,2000
    20180503,3000
    20180504,4000
```

File2.csv

```
    20180501,1000
    20180502,1000
    20180504,4000
```

File3.csv

```
    20180501,1000
    20180502,2000
    20180503,3000
```

Expected Output

```
    Date,Value1,Value2,Value3,Status
    20180501,1000,1000,1000,Match
    20180502,2000,1000,2000,Unmatch
    20180503,3000,,3000,Missing
    20180504,4000,4000,,Missing
```

Been trying around but none work. Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Please show your attempts. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
v=$(cat File1.csv File2.csv File2.csv | cut -d, -f1 | sort -u | sed 's/$/,/')
f() { { join -t, -v 1 - $1 <<<"$v"; cat $1; } | sort; }
join -t, <(join -t, <(f File1.csv) <(f File2.csv)) <(f File3.csv) \
| awk -F ',' '{ printf $0; if ($2 == "" || $3 == "" || $4 == "") print ",Missing"; else if ($2 == $3 && $3 == $4) print ",Match"; else print ",Unmatch"; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided your files are sorted, you can use `join` command to merge them together and `awk` to add the last column:

```
join -o auto -j1 -t, -a 1 -a 2 File1.csv File2.csv | join -o auto -j1 -t, -a 1 -a 2 - File3.csv | awk -F, 'match($0,",,|,$"){$5="Missing"}!$5{$5=($2!=$3||$2!=$4)?"Unmatch":"Match"}1' OFS=,
```

There are 2 `join` commands because it can only merge 2 files together.

The `awk` scripts checks for missing elements and then print the correct string in the last column.